# Magento: Print Fedex Request xml

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, fedex, xmlhttprequest

I am using magento 1.9 ver.

I need the xml code request which is sent from FedEx request. How to get it.

Comment: Enable Debug from admin panel and place one test order using FedEx. after that check `val/log` folder you will see file with name containing fedex

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MineshPatel. How to enable Debug from admin panel. Can i get full xml request in that log file?

Comment: added answer..... yes you will get full xml request in that log file

Comment: It gives only request parameters. Is it possible to get it as xml file ie., like `<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?><FDXRateAvailableServicesRequest/> .....`

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable Debug from admin panel and place one test order using FedEx. after that check val/log folder you will see file with name containing fedex.

> see below to enable debug

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

To print full xml, go to file `app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php`

edit function `_doRatesRequest()`

```
protected function _doRatesRequest($purpose)
{
    $ratesRequest = $this->_formRateRequest($purpose);
    $requestString = serialize($ratesRequest);
    $response = $this->_getCachedQuotes($requestString);
    $debugData = array('request' => $ratesRequest);
    if ($response === null) {
        try {
            $client = $this->_createRateSoapClient(true);
            $response = $client->getRates($ratesRequest);
            $this->_setCachedQuotes($requestString, serialize($response));
            $debugData['xml_request'] = $client->__getLastRequest();
            $debugData['xml_response'] = $client->__getLastResponse();
            $debugData['result'] = $response;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $debugData['result'] = array('error' => $e->getMessage(), 'code' => $e->getCode());
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    } else {
        $response = unserialize($response);
        $debugData['result'] = $response;
    }
    $this->_debug($debugData);
    return $response;
}

 protected function _createRateSoapClient($trace)
 {
            return $this->_createSoapClient($this->_rateServiceWsdl,$trace);
 }
```

What i have added

```
$debugData['xml_request'] = $client->__getLastRequest();
$debugData['xml_response'] = $client->__getLastResponse();
```

What i have updated

function `_createRateSoapClient()`

```
$client = $this->_createRateSoapClient(true);
```

> PS : This is just for debug purpose only else you should not edit core
>   files

Comment: Thanks @Minesh. I checked by as you mentioned here. but, i got empty response only. `[xml_request] => 
    [xml_response] => `.

Comment: updated  my answer. It should work now

Comment: Sorry. It is not worked. :(

Comment: paste you full code using [pastebin](https://pastebin.com) here

Comment: Yeah, Pls check it here https://pastebin.com/MVigvzaY

Comment: replace your code with  [this code](https://pastebin.com/sSC4KMbY) in your file

Comment: Yes, It is Worked. Can you pls mention what are the changes did.

Comment: check line 408 and 147 to 150. i have already mentioned in my answer but you did't updated your code :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58169/discussion-between-saravanan-ds-and-minesh-patel).